# Ajax call timing out in certain circumstances?

Tags: php, ajax, oracle

```
<?php
  include_once '../includes/db_connect.php';
  fetch_evt_values($conn, 7475, 2, 16);
  function fetch_evt_values($conn, $p_frm_id, $p_evt_id, $p_usr_id) {
    $p_rec_id = 0;
    $l_rslt_msg = '';
    $l_result   = array(
      'data' => array(),
      'msg'  => '0000'
    );

    $sql  = 'BEGIN PHPEVT.EV_MOD.FETCH_EVT_VALUES(';
    //$sql .= ':c_load_id,';
    $sql .= ':c_frm_id,';
    $sql .= ':c_evt_id,';
    $sql .= ':c_rec_id,';
    $sql .= ':c_usr_id,';
    $sql .= ':c_rslt';
    $sql .= '); END;';

    if ($stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql)) {
      $l_results = oci_new_cursor($conn);
      //oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_load_id',$p_load_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_frm_id',$p_frm_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_evt_id',$p_evt_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_rec_id',$p_rec_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_usr_id',$p_usr_id);
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':c_rslt',$l_results,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);
      if(oci_execute($stmt)){ //Execute the prepared query.
        oci_execute($l_results);
        while($r = oci_fetch_array($l_results,OCI_ASSOC)) {
          $l_evt_values = explode('|', $r['EVENT_VALUES']);
          foreach($l_evt_values as $l_evt_value) {
            list($l_ID, $l_value) = explode('@', $l_evt_value);
            $l_values[] = array('ID' => $l_ID, 'VALUE' => $l_value);
          }
          $l_result['data'][] = array(
            'LOAD_ID' => $r['LOAD_ID'],
            'REC_ID'  => $r['REC_ID'],
            'TRAIT'   => $l_values,
            'G_MSG'   => $r['G_MSG']
          );
          $l_rslt_msg = $r['G_MSG'];
        }
      } else {
        //echo 'cannot get user';
        $l_rslt_msg = '0005'; //PHP_MEMBER.FETCH_USER return error code
      }
    } else {
      //echo 'connect fail';
      $l_rslt_msg = '0006'; //Could not connect to database.
    }
    oci_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($l_result);
  }
?>
```

So on a webpage, when a user requests an event, a database call is made using this code to retrieve some values in the format :

"62@20000|65@15710|66@6|67@6|68@0|69@0|".

The PHP then breaks it apart by |, splits the ID@Value, puts everything into an array, then returns it as a JSON which is then parsed into a table. The latter works perfectly fine. But when this tries to fetch more than about 600 records or so, I get a 500 Internal Server Error, and I've figured it's something in this PHP that's handling the call.

I'm not convinced it's the database entirely, as a call for 3500 records with no further processing other than the JSON being returned is generally done in 5s or less.

Why would this code be failing at 500+ records? I've tried AJAX timeout of 0.

Comment: check your server's error logs for details about the 500. there's no point in flailing around with the code until you know WHAT the actual problem is.

Comment: I'll probably be waiting a bit then unfortunately. Until I have access to the server logs I can't do anything. Server admin won't get in until later today.

Comment: @Orpheus Maybe you could try to issue the same request from an other tool to check if you observe the same behavior?

Comment: It's only on an ajax call. If I were to invoke this same php on a simple html page, the call goes through even if it takes a small bit of time